# Deleting excel column in EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

How to move data validations when we delete an excel column in EPPlus?

Ex: I have an excel master template with some data validations at few columns.
when i delete a column prior to the validation column my column is deleted but validation remain at the original column.